# Upload file created in temporary directory into SharePoint using python

Tags: python, file-upload, sharepoint-api, sharepointdocumentlibrary, office365-rest-client

I am trying to upload a temp XML file that I created into Sharepoint using Python Script. Though I don't see any error when I run the code however the file was not uploaded into Sharepoint folder. Can you help me out.

```
# create XML attachment as temp file
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
path = os.path.join(tempdir)
temp_file = path + f'/XML_REPORT_{str(uuid.uuid4())}.xml'
with open(temp_file, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(tree_string)

print('temp file has been created')

base_path = 'https://company_name.sharepoint.com'
site_name = 'Testing'
doc_library = 'Shared%20Documents/General'

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username="test@xyz.com", password="abc123").GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})  

with open(temp_file, 'rb') as content_file:
    try:
      response = session.post( 
        url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='" 
        + temp_file + "',overwrite=true)",data=content_file)
      print('file added successfully')
    except Exception as err:
      print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

This is the url of my sharepoint https://company_name.sharepoint.com/sites/Testing/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx/?id=%2Fsites%2FTesting%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral&viewid=6357a30d%2D8562%2D4a01%2Dade1%2Dc1c413193931 I've already created a folder in it named General...

Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, please refer to the following document to upload file to SharePoint: https://github.com/iamlu-coding/python-upload2sharepoint

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding.